# React. Basic example of re-rendering using react-router. +100 rep

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm newbie. And I'm newbie at `React`. I'm trying `react-router`. I saw this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic.

I reproduced it on Codesandbox.io here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7jxq0j6qp0

I don't understand why the Menu is re-rendering itself when I change URL using menu's links.

[image]

If you open console you can see it.

**Why?**

I think it should not re-render itself. Just the route section. **Where am I wrong?**

Comment: That's a normal behavior. Your `<Menu/>` is inside the Router tag, so it'll re-render every time when you change to any route.

Comment: @MatheusReis it can't be outsdie because I use `<Link` component. What do you suggest?

Comment: why you don't want to Menu to be re-rendered?

Comment: Because is a negative perf impact. This is just a Basic Example. But I also wanna understand. It's a useless re-render!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your component as PureComponent. Since there is no prop changes right now it won't be re-rendered:

```
class Menu extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("Menu render() - ", Date.now());
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
      </div>
    );
 }
}
```

But, **please be aware of the negative sides** of this method for other use cases: [Dealing with Update Blocking](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking)

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why. PureComponent is heavy because sometimes is better to re-render that check if is to re-render.

Comment: I just wanna know why it has to re-render if nothing changes.

Comment: It is rerendering because location changes. I know this does not answer your question which is: `why it has to..` I think it is better to ask this on React Router's issues section of Github repository.

Comment: but it has to do with the link you posted in your answer? The Dealing with Update Blocking one?

Comment: It does not explain "why those components are rerendering" it just helps what if we or a third-party library do something causing to block this rerender and we have a problem about routing.